# PHP autoloading classes/subclasses

Tags: php, autoload

I'm brand new to PHP. To jump right into it, I have a Person class, a Customer class that extends Person, and a Basic Class that extends Customer. I also have a Book class (it's a Bookstore project) but that's not relevant to the issue.

In my init.php file I have my use statements for Book and Customer. According to this trash book I'm learning out of, anything that extends from Customer(Basic) should automatically be included with Customer. The autoloader function finds new instances of Book and Customer just fine, so I know there's nothing wrong there. But if I try to create a new instance of Basic, it doesn't find it. I'm smart enough to know that it's because Basic.php is in a subfolder from the other Class files. So my best guess is that I need a different autoloader for it. But it's frustrating because you'd think the book would tell me that, but I have followed the instructions 100% to a T.

Here is the contents of the init.php file:

```
<?php

use Bookstore\Domain\Book;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customer;

function autoloader($classname) {
    $lastSlash = strpos($classname, '\\') + 1;
    $classname = substr($classname, $lastSlash);
    $directory = str_replace('\\', '/', $classname);
    $filename = __DIR__ . '/src/' . $directory . '.php';
    require_once($filename); 
   } 
   spl_autoload_register('autoloader');


   
function checkIfValid(Customer $customer, array $books): bool {
    return $customer->getAmountToBorrow() >= count($books);
}

$book1 = new Book(9785267006323, "1984", "George Orwell", 12);
$book2 = new Book(9780061120084, "To Kill A Mockingbird", "Harper Lee", 2);



$customer1 = new Basic(5, "John", "Doe", "johndoe@email.com");
var_dump(checkIfValid($customer1, [$book1])); 
$customer2 = new Customer(7, "Mary", "Poppins", "mp@email.com"); 
var_dump(checkIfValid($customer2, [$book1]));

?>
```

Ignore the other functions and such, I'm only halfway through the lesson, but from what you see here, new Book and new Customer both pass correctly the the required $filename. But for Basic the compiler says it can't find /../../asic.php, which tells me "Basic" is the only thing being passed to $classname. Again, according to this stupid book, it's supposed to find Basic through Customer because Basic extends Customer.

Customer.php:

```
namespace Bookstore\Domain;

 class Customer extends Person {
```

Basic.php:

```
namespace Bookstore\Domain\Customer;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customer;

class Basic extends Customer {
```

I know the answer is probably obvious, and I apologize if this is too long, or any of the other things people get yelled at for, but according to this book, this is supposed to work as is.

Comment: Please add `use Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Basic;` to the top of your file

Comment: Its also a bit odd to have a file of `Bookstore\Domain\Customer` _and_ a namespace of `Bookstore\Domain\Customer`. Instead, I would expect there to be a folder at `Bookstore/Domain/Customers`  with 2 classes in it, Basic.php and Customer.php. Then Id expect the namespace in both of those files to be `Bookstore\Domain\Customers` and to use them in other files like `use Bookstore\Domain\Customers\Basic;` and `use Bookstore\Domain\Customers\Customer;`

Comment: I tried that before posting here. When I do that, it looks for Customer.php in the Customer folder.

Comment: Yeah that definitely makes sense. The only thing that has worked is just moving Basic.php to the same level as everything else and simply adding use\Bookstore\Domain\Basic;

Comment: If the book is just wrong, then I'm fine with that. But if the way the book is telling me to do this is supposed to work, then for future reference I want to make sure I understand why it's not.

Comment: Check out this link for details regarding how namespaces work  https://supunkavinda.blog/php/autoload-classes-namespaces

Comment: There's also a Premium class that extends from Customer at the same level as Basic. Those are the two files in the subfolder. So the namespace for Customer is Bookstore\Domain; and the two children Bookstore\Domain\Customer; if that changes anything in your previous comment.

Comment: To be honest I understand namespaces conceptually. I've googled it to death before I ended up here. I think the book is just not very good. I've caught numerous typos and random changes in syntax when a previous block of code is referenced a second time etc which is unfortunate, because situations like this where I can't be 100% sure that it's ME doing something wrong. But I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

> Again, according to this stupid book, it's supposed to find Basic through Customer because Basic extends Customer

The Basic class is not loaded yet, so there is no way to know what it is.

You need to tell the PHP the full name of Basic class

```
use Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Basic;
$customer1 = new Basic(5, "John", "Doe", "johndoe@email.com");
```

Or just

```
$customer1 = new Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Basic(5, "John", "Doe", "johndoe@email.com");
```

---

> I tried that before posting here. When I do that, it looks for Customer.php in the Customer folder.

Because you look for the file according to the class name in the autoload function. The full name of a class is `Namespace + \ + Classname`, in this case it is `Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Basic`, then the file name is `{root}/Domain/Customer/Basic`.